# All Sifre HaRamhal? (Rabbi Moshe Chayim Lutzato)

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, product-recommendation, jewish-books, mussar-ethics, ramchal

Is there a set that has "Kol Sifre HaRamhal"? The have "Kol Sifre HaHida" and other Rabanim, so maybe they'll also have all Sefarim of the Ramhal?

Comment: @Vram that we be *really* interesting to see.

Comment: @Vram, here is some of his poetry if you are interested in the secular things he wrote: http://www.ebay.com/itm/1st-edi-POETRY-SONGS-RAMCHAL-1945-Luzzatto-Hebrew-/370498587308

It is likely secular on the surface but apparently scholars have discovered mystical undertones in his writings.

Comment: http://ramhal.com/he/booklist.htm

Comment: He probably wrote too many books for this - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Chaim_Luzzatto#Bibliography